# USBInterfaceOpen always report kIOReturnExclusiveAccess error

Tags: kernel, usb, iokit, kernel-extension

Recently I encountered this problem headachely, I've already spend one week on this issue, but still failed. Hopefully, you can help me to kick this stone away, many thanks.

My Problem:
Our compony produce USB storage device for iPhone, actually there is a SDCard in this storage device. Now, we want to develop an Mac app to update firmware for this storage device. But every time I connect the storage device to Mac, Mac mounts it automatically, and I always fails with **kIOReturnExclusiveAccess** when invoke **USBInterfaceOpen**.

I also try to write a **codeless kext** to increase the probe score, but it still doesn't work. I don't know wether I go a wrong way, or some mistakes for writing the codeless kext, eg, write some wrong IOClass, wrong bundle ID.

My codeless kext info.plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
  <string>14E46</string>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.mophie.MyDriverTest3</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>MyDriverTest3</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>KEXT</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>1.0.3</string>
  <key>DTCompiler</key>
  <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
  <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
  <string>6E35b</string>
  <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
  <string>GM</string>
  <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
  <string>14D125</string>
  <key>DTSDKName</key>
  <string>macosx10.10</string>
  <key>DTXcode</key>
  <string>0640</string>
  <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
  <string>6E35b</string>
  <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
  <dict>
    <key>MyDriverTest3</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily</string>
        <key>IOClass</key>
        <string>IOService</string>
        <key>IOProviderClass</key>
        <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
        <key>bcdDevice</key>
        <string>256</string>
        <key>idProduct</key>
        <integer>4369</integer>
        <key>idVendor</key>
        <integer>6631</integer>
      </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>OSBundleRequired</key>
  <string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Below is the result from ioreg for my storage device:

```
space pack@1a122000  <class IOUSBDevice, id 0x100001773, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (300 ms), retain 9>
+-o IOUSBCompositeDriver  <class IOUSBCompositeDriver, id 0x100001775, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 4>
 +-o IOUSBInterface@0  <class IOUSBInterface, id 0x100001776, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (293 ms), retain 8>
  +-o IOUSBMassStorageClass  <class IOUSBMassStorageClass, id 0x100001777, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (201 ms), retain 9>
   +-o IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceNub  <class IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceNub, id 0x100001779, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (99 ms), retain 7>
    +-o IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00  <class IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00, id 0x10000177a, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0 (13 ms), retain 9>
     +-o IOBlockStorageServices  <class IOBlockStorageServices, id 0x10000177d, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (13 ms), retain 6>
      +-o IOBlockStorageDriver  <class IOBlockStorageDriver, id 0x10000177e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 47>
       +-o mophie SpacePack Media  <class IOMedia, id 0x100001784, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (12 ms), retain 11>
        +-o IOMediaBSDClient  <class IOMediaBSDClient, id 0x100001785, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 6>
         +-o IOFDiskPartitionScheme  <class IOFDiskPartitionScheme, id 0x100001788, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 6>
          +-o Untitled 1@1  <class IOMedia, id 0x10000178a, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 10>
           +-o IOMediaBSDClient  <class IOMediaBSDClient, id 0x10000178b, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 7>
```

Hopefully you can help me on this problem, many many many thanks, I preciate your help very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- The codeless kext approach should normally work for this kind of situation.
- Typically, your codeless kext would match (via IOProviderClass) an `IOUSBInterface`, not an `IOUSBDevice`. (e.g. see [the FTDI example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2315/_index.html))
- The bundle identifier for `IOService` is `com.apple.kpi.iokit`, not `com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily`, although I suspect that shouldn't be an issue.
- Is your codeless kext signed and installed correctly? (I have had instances where a kext in /Library/Extensions/ would not work at boot time, at least on OSX 10.9.x, unlike /System/Library/Extensions, although it should work OK for any hot-plugged devices.) Make sure the kext/personality cache is up to date, in other words, `touch` the Extensions directory whenever you update the kext.
- What does `kextutil -n` say?
- Have you tried setting the [`IOKitDebug`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/Articles/infoplist_keys.html) personality property to see if your kext is even getting a chance to match the device?
- Depending on how your firmware update commands are implemented, you may be able to use `ioctl`s on the device node. You can send raw SCSI requests to SCSI devices via ioctl. I'm not sure this will work for the USB mass storage class, but it definitely will for USB attached SCSI (UAS) or any other "true" SCSI device. Obviously this only helps if the your firmware update commands are exposed via SCSI.

If after all of that, you're still stuck, please provide some more information related to the above suggestions!

Comment: Thanks you very much for the FTDI example. it mentioned the long term solution is to modify the application to open the BSD layer serial port for communication with the FTDI hardware. A short term solution is to implement a codeless kext. Maybe I need research on the long term solution.

Comment: I tried as you suggestions, and still fails. I use kextutil -n, it said:
Warnings: 
    Personality CFBundleIdentifier differs from containing kext's (not necessarily a mistake, but rarely done): 
        MyDriverTest3

Code Signing Failure: not code signed
Warnings: 
    Personality CFBundleIdentifier differs from containing kext's (not necessarily a mistake, but rarely done): 
        MyDriverTest3

/System/Library/Extensions/MyDriverTest3.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).
I also disable the code sign by: **sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1**

Comment: Well, those are just warnings not errors, so if you install the kext in /Library/Extensions, and plug in the device, what happens? Do you get any console output? Etc.

Comment: The FTDI case is obviously different because it's a serial port. I don't know enough about your device to know what would work best in your case.

Comment: The kext plist I modified is: [MyTestDriver3.kext](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s73nhbk0j2d9snl/Info.plist?dl=0)

Comment: I didn't find a log locates at /var/log/system.log, it has some logs: 
log dir: /Volumes/SPACE PACK/.fseventsd getting new uuid: AE3311C2-42A6-4E21-9C5B-65181453F1DE
Aug  6 15:01:57 Evans-MacBook-Pro.local fseventsd[41]: Events arrived for /Volumes/SPACE PACK after an unmount request! Re-initializing.
Aug  6 15:01:57 Evans-MacBook-Pro.local fseventsd[41]: creating a dls for /Volumes/SPACE PACK but it already has one...
Aug  6 15:01:58 Evans-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[142]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery

Comment: could not open <</Volumes/SPACE PACK/.fseventsd/fseventsd-uuid>> (No such file or directory)
Aug  6 15:02:04 Evans-MacBook-Pro.local fseventsd[41]: Failed to load UUID.  Removing all old log files in /Volumes/SPACE PACK/.fseventsd
Aug  6 15:02:04 Evans-MacBook-Pro.local fseventsd[41]: log dir: /Volumes/SPACE PACK/.fseventsd getting new uuid: 06DB8AD1-B0C9-4B2B-86C5-3BC0B80AAAB3

Comment: This is the [system.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nwqbk5njdtaq0h/system.log?dl=0), you can search "MyDriverTest3", or our USB device "space pack"

Comment: One more thing that stands out: You haven't set an `IOProbeScore` in the personality dictionary. If your kext's probe score is lower than the default driver's, then it'll still load the default driver. Check the probe score of the driver that actually gets loaded, using IORegistryExplorer or `ioreg`, and then set you kexts probe score to something higher. One more thing: I assume you've checked that the kext's permissions are correct when you install it in /Library/Preferences or /System/Library/Preferences ?

Comment: FWIW Another option you have is subclassing the current driver, via a regular (non-codeless) kext, that then directly supports the firmware upload commands. Finally, you could hire someone who has experience in this area to just fix the problem for you…

Comment: Thanks for your precious guilds, I'll research more about non codeless kext.

Comment: Good luck! You should be able to find my email address pretty easily via my profile if you find you're still struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to use the low-level USB commands provided by [IOUSBInterfaceInterface](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOUSBInterfaceInterface_reference/) to connect to a USB mass storage interface and send some custom commands for updating the firmware.  Since that interface is claimed by the Apple mass-storage drivers, you probably aren't allowed to do that.

Instead, you might try making a second USB interface on your device which is a vendor-defined interface.  You would be able to connect to that interface and send arbitrary control transfers to your device.  Your device would then be a composite device if it is not already.

Alternatively, you might try some sort of hack to send signals over the mass storage interface.  For example, whenever a file with a special name is written to the device, that could be a signal to the device to go into bootloader mode for a firmware update.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for your reply, but we don't have a vendor-defined interface. Our product is selling now, due to iOS update, the iOS can not recognize the device. So we plan to develop a mac app for firmware update. The windows version is very easy, but for mac, **IOUSBInterfaceInterface** always fails. I'm so sad.

Comment: Well, bummer.  Isn't there a hardware procedure for getting into bootloader mode that the customers could follow?  Since it's always possible for the firmware to get corrupted or start misbehaving, the device should be designed with a special pin/button that is checked during power-up to determine whether to go into firmware update mode or not.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion is very nice, but our firmware doesn't have this mechanism.